# Error in connecting wcf service from android. Error: Failed to connect to /10.0.2.2

Tags: c#, java, android, wcf, ksoap2

While calling wcf ksoap2 from android.

```
htp.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelop);
```

I am getting this exception.

> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 52442)
>   after 20000ms: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)

My code was working fine till last night but now its not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is your server running?

Comment: A lot of possibilities. Restart the emulator, clean/restart the server, or as a last resort, restart the system. Always fixes for me.

Comment: well its working fine on emulator but not working on my phone

Comment: @yakhtarali ip address 10.0.2.2 should most probably not be accessible from your device. In emulator, this ip address is there for accessing the host system. If you want to access the system from a device, you'l have to use the actual network ip address of the system. And make sure that device is connected to the same network.

Comment: on my device that was working fine till last night

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obvious it's not any router-firewall related problem as you are under the same net, so there are only three possibilities:

1. There's nothing listening on that port on that IP
2. There's a local firewall on that machine that is blocking that connection attempt
3. You are not using WIFI so you're not under the same net.

Can you open that URL from your browser in your computer manually? If yes, I'd suggest using some debugging tool to trace TCP packets (I don't know either what kind of operating system you use on the destination machine; if it's some linux distribution, `tcpdump` might help).

All that assuming you have the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file.